# Perl : Parallel or multithread or Bloom-Faster or fork to fill hash from a file of 500 million lines

Tags: perl

what is the best solution to do this script faster like parallel runs ?

```
#!usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use threads;
open(R1 ,"<$ARGV[0]") || die " problem in oppening $ARGV[0]: $!\n";
my %dict1 : shared;
my $i=0;
while (my $l = <R1>){
     chomp($l);
     $l=~ s/\s$//;
     $l=~ s/^\s//;
     if ($l=~ /(.*)\s(.*)/){
          $i++;
          #print $1,"\n";
          #my $t = threads->create($dict1{$1}++);
          $dict1{$1}++;
     }
}
print $i, "\n";
close R1;
```

Comment: Could you re-edit your question? It looks like the whole thing is on one line at the moment....

Comment: @andrewsi: The whole thing was on a couple of lines. I've fixed it, more or less.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. When formatting code, make sure you have newlines, avoid tabs, lay out the code as you'd like it to look (4 spaces indentation per level is recommended), then select all the code and use the **`{}`** button above the edit box to indent so it appears as it does above. Then please add a question to the body of the text; you can't leave the whole question in the title/subject.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - you have a lot more patience than me!

Comment: what do you want to do with this hash of 500 million lines?  (note that perl threads are not lightweight; they take a long time to start up and any shared data is copied to each thread, so takes much more memory)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have mac 6,1 and 2 CPUs and 4 G ram. The execution is really heavy. Is there exist a solution to run on the 2 cpus ? I do not have something like nproc

Comment: for 500 million lines i would parse each one and stock them in a hash to compare them with a second huge file

Comment: how big are the keys on average?

Comment: Isn't what you posted IO-bound? If so, how is throwing more CPU at it going help.

Comment: What you posted can be replaced with `grep -c '\S\s\S' file`. An efficient way of doing what you want to do is hard to divine since we don't know what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks ikegami, no it is my first question on this forum. So I want these keys (60 ascii characters in average ) form first file to search them in a second file. Later I would synchronize the two files and extract informations in lines following the line containing the pattern '\s' is there exit dictionnary or a hash in shell ?

Answer (score 1):

You can make array of `$N` elements which correspond to equal parts of file,

```
my $N = 6;
my $step = int( $file_size/$N );
my @arr = map { ($_-1) * $step } 1 .. $N;
```

Then correct these numbers by seeking to file positions (`perldoc -f seek`), reading the rest of the line(`perldoc -f readline`), and telling corrected file position (`perldoc -f tell`).

Start `$N` threads where each already knows where to start with their extracting job, and join their results at the end. However you may find that reading from media is actual bottleneck as @ikegami already pointed out.

Comment: Could you please show me a short example ? how can I sleep the memory and when I can reactivate the reading of the rest, is the time of sleeping could be sufficient to prasing the read lines in memory and save the index in the hash . Shall i use readline function rather of seek ? thes issues in Perldoc is not fully understandable. I am a perl user not a developper. Thanks for help

Comment: @user3064106 it would need some adjustments => http://stackoverflow.com/a/16989501/223226

Answer (score 0):

The most likely case is that you're being limited by the speed that your data can be read from the disk ("I/O bound"), not by processing time ("CPU bound").  If that's the case, then there is *nothing* you can do with threads or parallel execution to speed this up - if it has any effect at all, parallelization would slow you down by forcing the disk to jump back and forth between the parts of the file being read by the different processes/threads.

An easy way to test whether this is the case would be to open a shell and run the command `cat my_data_file > /dev/null`  This should tell you how long it takes to just read the file from disk, without actually doing anything to it.  If it's roughly the same as the time it takes to run your program on `my_data_file`, then don't bother trying to optimize or speed it up.  You can't.  There are only two ways to improve performance in that situation:

1. Change the way your code works so that you don't need to read the entire file.  If you're dealing with something that will run multiple times, indexing records in the file or using a database may help, but that doesn't do any good if it's a one-shot operation (since you'd still need to read the whole file once to create the index/database).
2. Use faster storage media.

If you're not I/O bound, the next most likely case is that you're memory bound - the data won't all fit in memory at once, causing the disk to thrash as it moves chunks of data into and out of virtual memory.  Once again, parallelizing the process would make things worse, not better.

The solutions in this case are similar to before:

1. Change what you're doing so that you don't need all the data in memory at once.  In this case, indexing or a database would probably be beneficial even for a one-off operation.
2. Buy more RAM.

Unless you're doing much heavier processing of the data than just the few regexes and stuffing it in a hash that you've shown, though, you're definitely *not* CPU bound and parallelization will not provide any benefit.

Comment: my_data_file > /dev/null take lees time then the program execution (4 minutes). I that mean that I am memory bound ?

Comment: Being memory bound looks like the most likely case, yes. Assuming you're on a *nix-type system, you can verify that by using the `free` command to get a snapshot of memory usage while your program runs or `top` to watch it in real-time.